# Tornado OAuth2 Error in get_argument() (Facebook change)

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I have a problem that I can't work out. My code worked for localhost however how I have a proper domain setup i'm getting some strange problems trying to login with facebook. I have since moved to python 3.6

I have the following tornado setup code:

```
  handlers = [
     (r"/facebookAuth",FBAuth),
     # other handlers...
  ]

  # Settings dict for Application
  settings = {
     # static handler 
     # Set specific HTTP404 errors to Error404 Class
     "default_handler_class": Error404,
     "cookie_secret":"xxx",
  "facebook_redirect_uri":"https://www.example.com/facebookAuth",
     "facebook_secret":"xxx",
     "facebook_app_id":"xxx",
  }


class FBAuth(BaseHandler,tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
  async def get(self):
      if self.get_argument("code", False):
          print("not code")
          user = await self.get_authenticated_user(redirect_uri=self.settings["facebook_redirect_uri"],
                                                   client_id=self.settings["facebook_app_id"],
                                                   client_secret=self.settings["facebook_secret"],
                                                   code=self.get_argument("code"))

          print("******")
          print(user)

          firstName=user["first_name"]
          lastName=user["last_name"]

          # set cookie and start up code

      else:
          print("code")
          await self.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri=self.settings["facebook_redirect_uri"],
                                        client_id=self.settings["facebook_app_id"],
                                        scope=["email","public_profile"])
```

I can't work out the result of the code. It shows:

```
code 
not code
```

and crashes with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado-4.5.dev1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1474, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado-4.5.dev1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/gen.py", line 1045, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado-4.5.dev1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado-4.5.dev1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/gen.py", line 1051, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 6, in _wrap_awaitable
  File "/home/cs/charliesays/authHandlers.py", line 13, in get
    code=self.get_argument("code"))
  File "<string>", line 3, in __await__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado-4.5.dev1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/gen.py", line 1045, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado-4.5.dev1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado-4.5.dev1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/stack_context.py", line 314, in wrapped
    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado-4.5.dev1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/auth.py", line 983, in _on_access_token
    "access_token": args["access_token"][-1],
KeyError: 'access_token'
```

It seems there is a problem with the:

code=self.get_argument("code") in the call to get_authenticated_user()

Comment: hmm just looking at GIT it looks like this might have been fixed just 4 days ago https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/commit/28287ea88ddd2d407dbc1584b156a8db4578292c  still investigating....

Comment: Sorry should have checked GIT this has been fixed in the latest version on github 4 days ago. Thanks Ben and daynejones!